# Applying for job with recruiter who is on retainer with current company

Tags: recruitment, privacy

Im interested in a job on the market through a recruiter.
The recruiter is the one who placed me in my current role 5 years ago.
They also are on retainer with my current company, they are the recruiters my company approaches when we have a vacancy to fill.

Im worried that the recruiter will inform my current company i have been enquiring about other roles. The recruiter is after all paid a lot by my current company, it could be in their interests to inform of such events.

Is there a significant risk of the recruiter in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recruiting company was hired by your employer to fill open positions.  They are under no obligation to tell your employer that you are leaving.  I also believe it would be highly unethical for them to do so, as you are just as much a client of theirs as your employer.  They have their own reputation to uphold.

I think this boils down to how ethical you think the recruitment company is.  Do you believe the company holds the money they are making from your employer in higher regard than their moral standards?

Comment: thank you for the response. I have so far had 1 good experience with the company as they recruited me for my current role and 0 bad experiences, but true colors rarely shine through when everything is going well! 

I have however had more negative experiences with recruiters than positive, throughout my career.

I really want to think they are a reputable company, I'll think it over during Christmas holiday

Answer (score 3):

> Im worried that the recruiter will inform my current company i have
>   been enquiring about other roles. The recruiter is after all paid a
>   lot by my current company, it could be in their interests to inform of
>   such events.

Recruiters are typically paid per placement.  It's always in their best interest to place the next person, it doesn't matter what happened yesterday.

So it's in his interest to place you into another spot.  As an added bonus, it also opens up a spot (i.e. the job you're leaving) he'll know about it before any other recruiter and be well positioned to find someone for that too.